# 1 scratch off, 1 ticket or both?

Tags: probability, statistics

I have a problem that I would like some input on. Free beer(or soda) for best answer. I have several scratch offs and several tickets options. I have the maximum loss(item price) and I have the maximum potential win(max prize). Along with this information I have the probability of success for each item. How can I calculate which ticket/scratch off is most profitable for the risk and reward. I would like to calculate this first independently. Then I would like to see if a combination of a scratch off and a ticket would be more profitable.

P.S> I'm not actually buying anything just trying to use math to prove a point.

Comment: You can calculate your expected winnings for each game by multiplying the prize by the probability (or if more than one prize is possible, multiply each prize by its probability and add) and subtracting the cost. Is that what you mean?

Comment: @JackGarcia  There are far too many measures of risk to really answer this question.  If you would like to take a look at one of the simplest ones, check out: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sharpe_ratio.  Even reward is unclear - perhaps you would like to consider a Utility function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest way to asses risk/reward is to use the idea of [expected value](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expected_value). The link contains a lot of information, so I'll reduce it to the relevant basics.

If you have a random variable $X$ with possible values $x_1, x_2, \dots, x_n$, with the probability of $x_1$ being $p_1$, the probability of $x_2$ being $p_2$, and so on, then you can calculate the expected value of the variable using
$$E[X]=x_1 p_1 + x_2 p_2 + \dots + x_n p_n.$$

You can consider a ticket to be a random variable $T$. The ticket has a cost $c$, prize money $m$, and a probability of winning $p_w$. There are two possible outcomes for the ticket:

1. You win. This occurs with probability $p_w$ and gives a net monetary change of $m-c$ (you won the prize money, but you still payed for your ticket).
2. You lose. This occurs with probability $1-p_w$ and gives a net monetary change of $-c$ (you payed for the ticket but got nothing back).

Then we can use the formula above to calculate the expected value of the ticket:
$$E[T]=(m-c)(p_w)+(-c)(1-p_w)=m p_w - c$$

For example, let's say we have a ticket $T$ that costs $c=2$ dollars, prize money $m=100$ dollars, and probability of winning $p_w=.01$. Then the expected value is $$E[T]=m p_w - c=(100)(.01)-2 = -1.$$
That is, if you played this ticket a bunch of times, you would on average expect to lose about a dollar per ticket.

To determine the combination of tickets that will result in the maximum expected value, we just need to keep one simple fact in mind: *the expected values add* when tickets are played together. So if you have a series of tickets, then you will get your best chances by playing all tickets with a positive expected value together.

**But there's a catch.** Such lottery tickets, in reality, would never have positive expected values. If they did, the people running the lottery would on average be *losing money per ticket*. If the runners want to benefit (of course they do), the expected value of each ticket for the players needs to be negative. So when you play more and more tickets together, the expected value for your change in money just becomes more and more negative. Mathematically speaking, then, your best shot is not to play the lottery in the first place. :)